# I have an error installing thrift_client

Tags: ubuntu, thrift

When I install `thrift_client` using this command:

```
sudo gem install thrift_client -v '0.7.1'
```

I get this error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing thrift_client:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for strlcpy() in string.h... no
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fPIC -g -O2 -Wall -Werror  -o protocol.o -c protocol.c
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fPIC -g -O2 -Wall -Werror  -o struct.o -c struct.c
struct.c:28:1: ошибка: static-декларация «strlcpy» после неstatic-декларации
/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/missing.h:157:20: замечание: здесь была предыдущая декларация «strlcpy»
make: *** [struct.o] Ошибка 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thrift-0.7.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thrift-0.7.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

What's wrong?

I use Ubuntu 11.10, Thrift 0.8.0, Rails 3, Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Your error is probably `checking for strlcpy() in string.h... no`. Get Googling!

Answer (score 2):

Thrift_client has not yet updated its thrift gem dependency to 0.8.0, the version that builds on ubuntu.  So they say... [Update thrift pull request](https://github.com/twitter/thrift_client/pull/36)

I actually got it working by cloning a fix branch and building and installing it myself:

```
git clone https://github.com/bitlove/thrift_client.git
cd thrift_client/
rake build
gem build thrift_client.gemspec
gem install thrift_client-0.7.2.gem
```